React Native Web sockets. Getting 1006, OSStatus error -9807
Trying to connect to a credit cart swiping machine using websockets.  i am using react native as a POS application.  I am getting the following error when i try with iOS (ipad).
{"code": 1006, "isTrusted": false, "reason": "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)"}
Code:
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.1.2:8443');
            ws.onopen = () => {
                console.log("Connection Established")
                ws.send('Initiate Payment');
            };
            ws.onmessage = e => {
                console.log(e.data)
            }

            ws.onerror = e => {
                console.log(e.message);
            }

            ws.onclose = e => {
               console.log(e, e.code, e.reason);
            }

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.0",
I tried connecting through postman and i am successfully able to make connection

wss need a certificate.  this wont work with the regular WebSocket provided by react-native

how to get the certificate and where to provide them?
